# Can Apple Script be written and compiled in a non-english version?

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I have an AppleScript written in English whose task relates to Microsoft outlook.

If I change language to Spanish or French, the AppleScript doesn't work.

Can I write AppleScripts in other languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about syntax, then NO. Most programming languages are written in english and you have to use the correct syntax to make & compile a program.

What you can do is change the user-interface labels to match your language as well as the alert boxes titles ecc..

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But what if i need to support other languages.Can it be done in other way or it cannot be done.

Comment: I'll make it easy:

C syntax is something like : println("Your message here"). You can change the message but not the syntax which is calling the relative method/function

Comment: If you are trying to write a basic app without knowing anything about programming, check out Automator. This built-in mac app provides great feautures to make simple apps without writing anything

Comment: If this answer helped you, would you mind marking it as correct so that other users can see it ? Thanks

Comment: I am just thinking.. Please let me know if i am wrong .. consider i have a apple script

Comment: Sorry I don't understad. Something is still not clear ?

Comment: I am sorry here is my question.I have the below apple script   tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to activatetell application "System Events" tell process "Microsoft Outlook"tell menu bar 1tell menu bar item "Edit"tell menu "Edit"click menu item "Copy"end tellend tellend tellend tellend tell

Comment: I understand syntax can't be changed to other language but the parameters like "Edit" , "Copy" will be changed automatically when we change the language settings.                                                       Can we change these parameters automatically in the apple script based on the language preferences?

Comment: Use CMD+F to find & replace "Edit" and "Copy" titles to whatever you want

Comment: Thanks FoxNos..i am trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

The original intent for AppleScript was that it would use 'simple English', and that with the open scripting architecture, the original intent was to develop Applescript in other human languages as well. That never matriculated. So, no, you must use the English syntax.